# pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, scikit-learn

```
pyarrow version is 0.17.1
pandas version is 1.0.4
pyspark 2.3.4
```

I have a pyspark dataframe with 4 columns as shown below:

```
  A      B       C        D
-----  -----   -----    -----
  1      2       3      My Name is cat
  2      4       5      I like to code
```

I need to add another column 'prediction' to the dataframe based on the column 'D'. The model, which predicts, expects a pandas dataframe with single column as input and returns numpy array as output. So, I wrote a Scalar Pandas UDFs to implement it.

```
@pandas_udf(ArrayType(BooleanType()),PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def t_func(pdf):
    predict=classifier.predict(pdf)[:,1]
    #Note: classifier.predict returns values as follows array([[0.706,0.293],[0.986,0.0713]])
    #Note: predict values would look like as follows array([0.293],[0.0713])
    #Note: type of predict is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    predictions = predict > decision_threshhold
    #Note: predictions values would look like as follows array([False,False])
    #Note: type of predictions is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    return pd.Series(predictions)

X = X.withColumn('prediction",t_func('D'))
```

Final output should look like as follows:

```
  A      B       C        D                 prediction
-----  -----   -----    -----               -------------
  1      2       3      My Name is cat     False
  2      4       5      I like to code      False
```

But, I get the following error and not sure what was the issue:

> pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: NumPyConverter doesn't implement <list<item: bool>> conversion

Comment: Any help to solve this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in the return type from the UDF function. As it returns a panda series containing boolean values but yarrow does not have a direct conversation for this specific datatype.

You can try converting the boolean values to integer -

```
predictions = (predict > decision_threshhold).astype(int)
```